# Statistic method for comparing feature profile

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, generalized-linear-model, chi-squared-test

I have three groups of people: Group 1, Group 2, Group3. Each group has about 20 people.
And I collected data on the proportion of certain features for each person.

| Group | Person ID | feature 1 | feature 2 | .... | feature 20 | total of features |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A1 | 20% | 5% | 25% | 3% | 100% |
| A | A2 | 30% | 10% | 2% | 0% | 100% |
| B | B1 | 34% | 0% | 45% | 25% | 100% |

.......

So each person is having a different profile of features - but I want to compare whether the feature profile differs on the group level, and if differs, where is the source of the difference. The statistical methods I could think of are:

- Chi-squared-test on group level (averaging the percentage over people in each group), but then I lose individual data.
- Generalised mixed effects model glm(Group ~ feature 2 + feature 3 .... + feature 19 + (1|Person ID)), but it does not seem to answer the research question.

Any suggestion?